# Simulate a population of agents and compute averaged cumulative efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code which is a model where each agent makes decisions and accumulates efficiency over time.

With the `def scenario` function, the idea is to create a simulation that returns the averaged cumulative_efficiency (i.e. `mean_eff`) of a population of agents at each time step.

Is there a more pythonic or efficient way to implement this idea?

```
import numpy as np
import string
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Actions:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.mean = 0
        self.T = 0

    def choose(self):
        return np.random.randn() + self.m


    def update(self, x):
        self.T += 1
        self.mean = (1 - 1.0 / self.T) * self.mean + 1.0 / self.T * x


def agent_type(m1, m2, m3, eps, T):
    actions = [Actions(m1), Actions(m2), Actions(m3)]
    data = np.empty(T)

    for i in range(T):
        if i < 2:
            #efficiency at t0
            x = 0
        else:
            # epsilon
            p = np.random.random()
            # the larger epsilon is the more likely it is to explore new actions
            if p < eps:
                j = np.random.choice(3)
            else:
                j = np.argmax([a.mean for a in actions])
            x = actions[j].choose()
            actions[j].update(x)

        # plot
        data[i] = x
    cumulative_efficiency = np.cumsum(data) / (np.arange(T) + 1)

    return cumulative_efficiency
    

def scenario(m1, m2, m3, eps, T, pop):
    a = []
    for agent in range(pop):
        agent=agent_type(m1, m2, m3, eps, T)
        a.append(agent)
        print(a)
    mean_eff=np.mean(a,0)
    return mean_eff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c_1 = scenario(0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 100000, 100)

plt.plot(c_1, label='eps = 0.5')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `N`? You've left it undefined.

Comment: @Reinderein thanks for letting me know. I have fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

Add PEP484 typehints to your function signatures, e.g.

```
def agent_type(m: np.ndarray, eps: float, T: int) -> np.ndarray:
```

Don't use `np.random.random()`; that's deprecated in favour of the new generators.

I don't think that a class is a very good idea here. Typical Numpy code would represent each "action" as a separate column within one array per property: an array for `m` (with three members); and probably an array for historical means with three columns.

Your algorithm is going to be difficult to speed up without switching to a better language. Your action update function represents a recurrence relation. `scipy.signal.lfilter` might, if you're lucky, be able to accelerate this.

One thing that can be trivialially vectorised is `data`:

```
rand = default_rng(seed=0)
data = np.empty((N, n_actions))
data[:2] = 0
data[2:, :] = rand.normal(loc=m, size=(T-2, n_actions))
```

Note that you should not be adding `m` by yourself, but instead using it as the `loc` parameter of the normal distribution.

Your plot needs a title and axis labels.

Comment: This is very useful @Reinderien, but some aspects of your suggestions are not totally intuitive for my level. Could you share your implementation of the code?

Comment: My implementation of the code is not complete and won't help you. If you have specific questions I am happy to answer them.

Comment: what is n_actions?

Comment: The number of actions, in your case 3.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i did: n_actions=3. Running this c_5 = scenario(np.ndarray([1,2,3]), 0.5, 100000, 100), i get this error line 31, in agent_type data[2:, :] = rand.normal(loc=m, size=(N - 2, n_actions)). I suppose this solution involves substantially modifying the code and functions.